# Disable Mobile Stylesheet in Order to Load Full Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, stylesheet, media-queries

I am using media queries to load a mobile stylesheet. I want users to be able to click a link that will disable this stylesheet so they will we able to view the full site if they wish. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is your CSS inline?  Or in a file?  If it's in a file then I think you are out of luck.  It may be possible to do this via jQuery if your CSS is inline.  Please post your CSS specific to the problem so we can get a better look at your code.

Comment: Hi Lokase. The CSS is not inline, it is a file. 
<style type="text/css" media="all and (max-width: 480px)">
@import url("path-to-css");
</style>

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the stylesheet by adding the "disabled" attribute to it and add the stylesheet without the media-query.

There is a good (but old) article on ALA on changing stylesheets:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/